# Make Eclipse IDE run the code slower

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My apologies in advance if my question sounds primary.

I am writing a test with Selenium and Java, the test runs fast so that I cannot easily check if something has been done or not, it writes some logs in the Eclipse console but still I as a human being cannot follow them in time, I now that I can use `Thread.sleep()` to make my code slower, but is there any way that I can make Eclipse run the code slower?

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you dont actually need to make the compiler "slower", don't know if that is possible, but you should use breakpoints in your code and use the debugger.

Here is a tutorial if you want follow one:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You should place breakpoints in your code where you want it to slow down. Then run your program in debug mode. You will be able to freeze your program at any point you wish to look at the state of it.

Comment: I needed to use a conditional break point evaluating `true` with a count hit of `1000` (100 was too fast, 1000 gave me two seconds to click the button) so I could catch the source of a stack overflow